# Div with background color inside container has less width than its container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap, the container is 915px width, I am running in mobile browser.
The problem is the div with background color is supposed to occupy the whole width, but there are some white margins.
how can i extend the div a few pixel in each side?

```
    <div class="container"> 

    <div class="" style="width:100%;height:90px;background-color:Red;margin-left:50px;">


    </div>

    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: If you use Bootstrap 3 `.container` has padding. Try to use negative horizontal margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a different container class from Bootstrap?

Perhaps "container-fluid" as described below and on the Bootstrap component page - http://getbootstrap.com/css/

**Containers**

Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable.

Use .container for a responsive fixed width container.

```
<div class="container">
  ...
</div>
Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.

<div class="container-fluid">
  ...
</div>
```

You could also mix and match via Media Queries and JavaScript if you wanted to. For example on certain Media Query dimension triggers compensate for the style overrides you wish to be used.

**Reference:**

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a negative margin

```
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px;
```

Comment: Probably want to avoid negative values at all costs unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted, it looks like the inner div is 100% *of the container.*

Either put the inner div outside of the container or make the container 100% width (there are other bootstrap containers for this).

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `.row`:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row" style="
        width:100%;height:90px;background-color:Red;margin-left:50px;">
    </div>
</div>
```